# Structure of google project in developer console

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I am implementing Google Drive API and Google Sheets API to my application. How should I go about structuring the project in Google Developers console?

First I created the Drive connection and Oauth2 for it, then filled the verification request with scopes

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`

which was verified.

Then I created another Oauth2 for Sheets API and after trying to verify the scopes

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

But my request got denied with message that I already have `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope.

So should I create separate project for each API or use same Oauth2 for both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each application is a project in Google developer console.  Assuming you are trying to access user data then you should create Oauth2 credentials and request all of the scopes that you will need for the application.

If the application is using

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Then you would need to active all three APIs in the Google Developer console.   However I think that drive.file scope gives you the same access to all the files in Google drive there fore you dont need the spreadsheets scope.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app

vs

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets   View and manage your spreadsheets in Google Drive

Comment: Oh thanks I wasn't sure about that from reading docs. I am actually implementing two separate features, one will allow user to import his data to spreadsheets and the other will allow to upload content from my application to his Drive. They also have separate login, so I think it should be divided into two projects.

Comment: You can make more the one oauth2 client but its best to have them in separate projects so that they arent both using the same quota.

Comment: Then it's strange that they responded during verification that I am basically trying to verify scopes from another Oauth2 client which were already verified.

Comment: You are verified at the project level not the client level